# How to combine these two Queries in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my View, I need to show a list with the name of each City with the available services in that area (City Services) below each name.  This involves two queries.  But, how can I combine them and show that simple list?

The Models...

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :city_services, :dependent => :delete_all
end

class CityService < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :city
end
```

The Controller...  This is where I need help.

```
@county = params[:county]
@city_ids = City.where("county = ?", @county).map { |c| c.id }
@city_services = CityService.where( :city_id => @city_ids )
```

But, there are multiple services for each City, so I can't just list city_services, or cities will be listed multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

try this (I assume the cities table is called cities):

```
@city_services = CityService.joins(:city).where(cities: {country: params[:country]})
```

If you want a distinct list:

```
@city_services = CityService.joins(:city).where(cities: {country: params[:country]}).uniq
```

Comment: Pretty close!  Except there are multiple Services for each City, so in the query results I have some Cities listed twice.  Is there some simple Ruby I can use to combine the query results with the same City into one record, so that I can list the results in the View without having certain cities show up twice?

Comment: For example this city has two services and shows up twice, how can I combine these two results?:  #<CityService id: 979, city_id: 15, city_name: "Amador City", service: "Cold Fusion", available: true, created_at: "2013-05-15 08:05:07", updated_at: "2013-05-15 08:05:07">, #<CityService id: 15, city_id: 15, city_name: "Amador City", service: "Clear Fiber", available: true, created_at: "2013-05-14 20:41:21", updated_at: "2013-05-14 20:41:21">

Comment: What should the result list look like? Are you trying to list all the cities that have some service? All the services per city?

Comment: If all you want is to list the cities you can add `uniq` to the query and that's it:  `@city_services = CityService.joins(:city).where(cities: {country: params[:country]}).uniq`